bitbake b2qt-embedded-qt6-image fails for STM32mp15-disco
I'm building the target image in yocto with the boot2qt manifest 6.7.xml.
Before creating the full image, I bitbake my custom recipe, and after solving some errors it built correctly, here's a post where I solved some of those errors: https://forum.qt.io/topic/159562/how-to-create-recipe-for-qt-quick-app-in-yocto?_=1731156856435
Then, I added my custom recipe to the local conference and started bitbake with b2qt-embedded-qt6-image. The error:
| cd /home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/6.7.3/build/src/core && /home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/6.7.3/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/ninja -C /home/vboxuser/yocto/build-stm32mp15-disco/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtwebengine/6.7.3/build/src/core/Release/arm QtWebEngineCore
| ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
| 
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/vboxuser/yocto/sources/meta-qt6/recipes-qt/qt6/qtwebengine_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 8110 tasks of which 7847 didn't need to be rerun and 2 failed.
NOTE: Build completion summary:
NOTE:   do_populate_sysroot: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 16 scratch)
NOTE:   do_deploy_source_date_epoch: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 13 scratch)
NOTE:   do_create_spdx: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 15 scratch)
NOTE:   do_create_runtime_spdx: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 15 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package_qa: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 9 scratch)
NOTE:   do_recipe_qa: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 15 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 10 scratch)
NOTE:   do_packagedata: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 10 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package_write_ipk: 92.6% sstate reuse(125 setscene, 10 scratch)
NOTE:   do_populate_lic: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 13 scratch)

Summary: 2 tasks failed:
  /home/vboxuser/yocto/sources/meta-boot2qt/meta-boot2qt/recipes-qt/boot2qt-addons/boot2qt-demolauncher_git.bb:do_unpack
  /home/vboxuser/yocto/sources/meta-qt6/recipes-qt/qt6/qtwebengine_git.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 6 WARNING messages.
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages, returning a non-zero exit code.


I'm unsure what to do because I already compiled my custom Qt app in my custom recipe and am not adding the Qt web engine there.
My qt app was created using qt 6.7.3. Should I be using another version in the meta-qt6 or even downgrade to meta-qt5?
I'm using boot2qt 6.7.3 manifest and MACHINE=stm32mp15-disco and image b2qt-embedded-qt6-image.
I'm using meta-qt6 layers and the nanbield meta-st layer which is the one that matches.
This is my bb file in my custom recipe(which builds ok if I only bitbake the custom recipe)
SUMMARY = "This is the GUI for Hespect Software medical device"
DESCRIPTION = "Recipe created by bitbake-layers"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SECTION = "Mysection"

DEPENDS += " qtbase \
             qtdeclarative-native \
             qtdeclarative \
             qtquick3d \
             qtcharts"
             
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${STAGING_DIR_HOST}${prefix}"

SRC_URI += "file://main.cpp"
SRC_URI += "file://CMakeLists.txt"
SRC_URI += "file://CMakeLists.txt.user"
SRC_URI += "file://Backendsensors.h"
SRC_URI += "file://Backendsensors.cpp"
SRC_URI += "file://brushfactory.h"
SRC_URI += "file://brushfactory.cpp"
SRC_URI += "file://Main.qml"

# Add SVG images from the assets/images folder
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/battery-full.svg"
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/battery-mid.svg"
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/rss-low.svg"
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/signal-full.svg"
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/signal-mid.svg"
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/battery-low.svg"
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/rss-full.svg"
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/rss-mid.svg"
SRC_URI += "file://assets/images/signal-low.svg"

            
S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit qt6-cmake
inherit populate_sdk_qt6

I have no idea what to do next. If this is possible to do starting the yocto environment from a st manifest I would be happy to change it.

I decided to follow the st documents which at least resulted in the image being built correctly.
